# When should I use # and = in ASP.NET controls?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have been using ASP.NET for years, but I can never remember when using the # and = are appropriate.

For example:

```
<%= Grid.ClientID %>
```

or

```
<%# Eval("FullName")%>
```

Can someone explain when each should be used so I can keep it straight in my mind? Is # only used in controls that support databinding?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [In ASP.NET, what are the different ways to inline code in the .aspx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219).

Comment: I've didn't check the theory behind this, but <%# seems to be evaluated BEFORE <%=, so even if accessed variable may exist and is set during lifetime, it may return null. I've just lost a few time to fix a such issue (very tricky situation in my case), so I thought it could be useful to share it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<%= %> is the equivalent of doing Response.Write("") wherever you place it.

<%# %> is for Databinding and can only be used where databinding is supported (you can use these on the page-level outside a control if you call Page.DataBind() in your codebehind)

[Databinding Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)

Comment: see Gui Starbuck answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115159/when-should-i-use-and-in-asp-net-controls/115205#115205  for the differences between <%= and <%#

Answer (score 44):

There are a couple of different 'bee-stings':

- `<%@` - page directive
- `<%$` - resource access
- `<%=` - explicit output to page
- `<%#` - data binding
- `<%--` - server side comment block

Also new in ASP.Net 4:

- `<%:` - writes out to the page, but with HTML encoded

Also new in ASP.Net 4.5:

- `<%#:` - HTML encoded data binding

Comment: <%$ is not just for resource access, but for ExpressionBuilders - of which ConnectionStrings, AppSettings, and Resource are included in ASP.NET. It's also trivial to write your own. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.aspx

Comment: Quite a nice explanation here: http://michielvoo.net/blog/expressions-vs-statements-part-2-asp-net-code-block-types/

Comment: Where does the phrase *bee-stings* come from?

Comment: @Lankymart in the default Visual Studio colour schemes these were highlighted in black and yellow, so `%>` looked a little like a bee sting.

Comment: Thanks, I was just intrigued where the phrase came from in relation to ASP code blocks, I've never heard before.

Comment: Looks like link you posted died back in 2013, but can still be accessed here [Expressions vs. Statements, part 2: ASP.NET Code Block Types via Archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20130203221323/http://michielvoo.net/blog/expressions-vs-statements-part-2-asp-net-code-block-types/)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a [great blog post by Dan Crevier](http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx) that walks through a test app he wrote to show the differences.

In essence:

- The <%= expressions are evaluated at render time
- The <%# expressions are evaluated at DataBind() time and are not evaluated at all if DataBind() is not called.
- <%# expressions can be used as properties in server-side controls. <%= expressions cannot.

Comment: "<%= expressions cannot." Because <%= %> is a shortcut for Response.Write which happens _*after*_ the page is rendered and the response is being streamed back to the browse.

Comment: These are the real differences