# What is the difference between <% %> and <%=%>?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between `<% %>` and `<%= %>` in ASP.NET MVC? And when to use which?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115159). MVC hasn't changed how these bee-stings work, just how often they're used.

Basically:

- `<%` - execute code
- `<%@` - page directive
- `<%$` - resource access
- `<%=` - explicit output to page
- `<%#` - data binding
- `<%--` - server side comment block

Also new in ASP.Net 4:

- `<%:` - writes out to the page, but with HTML encoded

Comment: bee-stings, nice, hadn't heard that one.. :) great response btw

Answer (score 10):

<%= %> writes to the output stream (usually html) while <% %> is for executing arbitrary script code.

Answer (score 8):

Say you have a method on your page, called "SayHello":

```
protected string SayHello()
{
    return "Hello!";
}
```

And on your page, you have these statements:

```
first: <%= SayHello() %>
second: <% SayHello() %>
```

Your output will be:

```
first: Hello!
second:
```

when you use <%= %>, what you put in there is inserted into the html at that position. If you use <% %>, you're just inserting some code into your page.

Answer (score 3):

<%= echos the statement out.

<% just runs it.