# What is the difference between the various "<% %>" items

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When should I use # and = in ASP.NET controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115159/when-should-i-use-and-in-asp-net-controls)
>   [What is the difference between <% %> and <%=%>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197047/what-is-the-difference-between-and)

I have seen samples with "<%#", "<%=" and "<%". First of all, is there a name for these things? Second, where can I find a reference that tells what the different versions do? I have tried searching, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the differences at (there are some you missed and I'm not going to re-key all the information when it's already referenced elsewhere):

[Inline ASP.NET Tags...Sorting Them All Out](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

They're commonly referred to as "bee stings".

[What is the difference between <% %> and <%=%>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197047/what-is-the-difference-between-and)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between <% %> and <%= %> is discussed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135(VS.80).aspx).  In essence the <%= %> variant is used used to output the result of an expression, while the version without the = is just used to execute some code.

The <%# %> version is used for data binding, and its use is discussed on [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860) Microsoft support page.

The official name for this syntax is Server-Side Scripting Delimiters.  Much more info can be found in the answers to [question 649428](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a handy little article that I found:

http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc).aspx