# Why to use # in embedded code asp.net

Tags: asp.net

when to use `#` used inside `<% %>` ?

`<%# Eval()%>`       what is the use of `#` in this ?

what are the other options available like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between <% %> and <%=%>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197047/what-is-the-difference-between-and)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%#%>` is known as the binding expression. The data-binding expressions can be used in attributes of server tags to assign calculated values to properties. Also they can be used like a separate tag.

You may check [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112) for details

> **<%# ... %>**
>
> The data-binding expression creates binding between a server control
>   property and a data source when the control’s DataBind method of this
>   server control is called on the page.

The following example shows how to use the data-binding expression to bind the string from a function to the Text property of a label:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<script runat="server">
    Protected Function SayHello() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function

    Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        lblHello.DataBind()
    End Sub
</script>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblHello" runat="server" Text="<%# SayHello%>"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> **what are the other options available like this?**

From the same MSDN site. You may find the option like:-

- <% ... %>  embedded code blocks
- <%= ... %> displaying expression
- <%@ ... %> directive expression
- <%# ... %> data-binding expression
- <%$ ... %> expression builder
- <%-- ... %> server-side comments block

Comment: Thanks for the example . What are the other option available ?       I have seen <%= %>,<%$ %> . What all this mean ?

Comment: @Dhinesh:- You are welcome! Other option available means? I have added a MSDN link you can check all the option there!

Comment: :I have gone through that link . Its very useful to me . Thank you .