# Regularexpression validationexpression from constant defined in another project in a struct

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, data-binding

I have a `Repeater` with a `TextBox` and a `RegularExpressionValidator` (REV) on every row. I bind the validationexpression for REVs in the aspx by doing,

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexTeam" ErrorMessage="myerrormessage" 
       ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" Display="None" 
       ControlToValidate="txtTeam" runat="server" 
       ValidationExpression='<%# MyNamespace.Constants.RegularExpression.myvalidationexpressionconstant %>'>
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

This works fine.

Now I have another place(not within the `Repeater`) with the same kind of `TextBox` and an REV. I do the same:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexStatus" ErrorMessage="myerrormessage" 
        ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup2" Display="None" 
        ControlToValidate="txtStatus" runat="server" 
        ValidationExpression='<%# MyNamespace.Constants.RegularExpression.myvalidationexpressionconstant %>'>
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The second one does not work. It does not accept any input. In the page source, there is no `regexstatus.validationexpression`. The `regexteam.validationexpression` exists as expected. Any ideas?

PS: The constants are defined in a separate project in a struct. I cannot make it a static class.

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: no difference expect the first one works and the second one doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the one not in the `Repeater`, there is no 'bind' action happening so the `<%#` code is not firing.

You can call a bind at the page level to cause it to fire if you want but not sure what the side effects of that would be or you can use `<%=` instead that just executes regardless of binding.

Comment: "<%=" does not resolve the constant to the actual expression, right.. is that what you meant?

Comment: @user3797607 the `<%=` will just execute the code and write the result as the output to the html source.  The `<%#` does the same thing but it is triggered by a DataBind event.  Because your second control has no DataBind event occurring, the code never executes.

Comment: If I do, "<%= ", the page source shows regexstatus.validationexpression = MyNamespace.Constants.RegularExpression.myvalidationexpressionconstant

Comment: You may need to ensure whatever you are 'reading' is valid and not just outputting a string.  It should execute the code as if it was run and display the result. Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197047/what-is-the-difference-between-and

Comment: Thanks, but looks like I have no option to do it this way?  <% gives     "<% Mynamespace.Constants.RegularExpression.myvalidationexpressionconstant %>"   :(

Comment: It's <%= not <%  also you could store the value in your pageload event and then just put the variable in its place

Comment: No, <%= does not work. I just see the same "<% Mynamespace.Constants.RegularExpression.myvalidationexpressionconstant %>"

Comment: Then try assigning it to a global var in your PageLoad and then use that variable...  There must be more going on if this does work.

Comment: yea..i was trying to avoid that. but looks like I don't have another option. I will just do a textstatus.databind and play around i guess. Thanks again for your time..