# Where can I find information on code blocks?

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know a good website that summarises what you can do with code blocks (i.e. <% <%= <%# etc) in ASP.Net?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question should be helpful:
[When should I use # and = in ASP.NET controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115159/when-should-i-use-and-in-aspnet-controls)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a MSDN page: [MSDN Embedded Code Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx)

```
<%    -  any code

<%=   -  shortcut for Response.Write()    

<%#   -  is for binding

<%--  -  is for comments
```

Comment: You're missing <%@ and <%$, at least.