# In ASP.Net, what is the difference between <%= and <%#

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.Net, what is the difference between `<%= x %>` and `<%# x %>`?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

See this question:
[When should I use # and = in ASP.NET controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115159/when-should-i-use-and-in-asp-net-controls)

---

Summary from those answers:

There are a several different 'bee-stings':

- `<%@`  - Page/Control/Import/Register [directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8syafc7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- `<%$`  - [Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx) access and [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx) building
- `<%=`  - Explicit output to page, equivalent to `<% Response.Write( ) %>`
- `<%#`  - [Data Binding.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)  It can only used where databinding is supported, or at the page level if you call `Page.DataBind()` in your code-behind.
- `<%--` - [Server-side comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4acf8afk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) block
- `<%:`  - Equivalent to `<%=`, but it [also html-encodes the output](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Joel for providing links and a very clear answer.

Answer (score 5):

`<%#` is [data binding expression syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx).

`<%=` resolves the expression returns its value to the block ([Embedded code block reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx)) - effectively shorthand for `<% Response.Write(...); %>`

Answer (score 2):

<%# is the databinding directive, <%= is a shortcut for "Response.Write"

Answer (score 2):

<%= x %> is shorthand for Response.Write()

<%# x %> indicates a databind.

<%    %> indicates server-executable code.