# Send values from other controls to User Control properties in .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, query-string

Is there a way pass values from other controls (e.g. "selected value of dropdownlist", "value from query string") to a User Control using a property within the tag itself and NOT from the code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, you just need to use the `<% %>` in the presentation code.  Your code would look something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlFoo" runat="server">
    ...
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox id="txtBar" runat="server" Text='<%# ddlFoo.SelectedValue %>' />

<%-- For query string --%>
<asp:TextBox id="txtBar" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Request.QueryString["Key_Value"] %>' />
```

The SO post [In ASP.Net, what is the difference between <%= and <%#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517721/in-asp-net-what-is-the-difference-between-and-closed) gives a good listing of the different binding mechanisms you can use.

Comment: @LFSR Consulting: Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: @LRSR Consulting:  I tried your example and it sticks <%= ddlFoo.SelectedValue %> into the textbox as the value (as if it's just a string)

Comment: @Brian, that's my bad, I can never remember which value to use; try: <%# ddlFoo.SelectedValue %>

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. For example

```
 <uc1:CompetitionClassification ID="CompetitionClassification" runat="server" OnlyTopFive="True" />
```

in this case, the parameter OnylTopFive is passed within tag of my custom control.

then in server side of my control, i have :

```
private bool onlyTopFive;
  public bool OnlyTopFive
    {
        get
        {
            return this.onlyTopFive;
        }
        set
        {
            this.onlyTopFive = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to pass values from other controls, not hard-coded values.