# What are these called <% ... %>? And what ways can they be used in a page

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, tags

In a .Net web form...

What are these special tags called?

I know of 2:  `<%-- comment --%>`   for comments

and `<%# used with Eval and Bind #>`

So what does the # signify? Are there more?

I know you can put some basic logic and function calls in there but I've never found anything that really describes how that can be used and should be used.

I hope this isn't a duplicate but it's really hard to search for `<%#`

Comment: Duplicate/Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517721/in-asp-net-what-is-the-difference-between-and-closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115159/when-should-i-use-and-in-asp-net-controls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're also called bee-stings:
[In ASP.Net, what is the difference between <%= and <%#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517721/in-asp-net-what-is-the-difference-between-and)

Answer (score 3):

Server tags. They are called server tags.

Of course there are more.

`<%= "string constant" %>` - it will output a given string to the HTML output

`<%= BO.Customer.GetName () %>` - will do the same with the function that returns a string result

`<% RenderMyCoolControl %>` - without the "=" character, it is supposed that your function will render something to the HTML output using Response.Write

Or you can use that directly: `<% Response.Write ("string constant") %>`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> 

Used for Binding Expressions; such as Eval and Bind, most often found in data controls like GridView, Repeater, etc

> Are there more?

Take a look here:

[Inline tags](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly complete list here:

> [ASP.NET "special" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

And as the accepted answer on there states, they are "[Server Side Scripting Tags](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windows2000serv/reskit/iisbook/c06%5Fasp%5Fserver-side%5Fscripting.mspx?mfr=true)"