# Asp.Net - what is <%$?

Tags: asp.net

I should know this by now, but I don't, and for some reason, I am not finding the answer on Google, so I thought I'd try here.

I know that `<%=  %>` is the equivalent of `Response.Write()`

And I've seen `<%#  %>` for databinding.

However, today I noticed something new, and even though I can see what it's doing, I am looking for the official documentation on this.  In one of my web pages, I see

```
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SomeConnectionString %>"
```

So what does `<%$  %>` do?

Comment: Thank you to all who answered. Both @Thomas Jaskula and @Joewl Coehoorn's answers were good and helpful, and got voted up, and I had a hard time choosing which to accept. I decided to use @Thomas' answer because if the link I was looking for.  Thank you both!

Comment: possible duplicate of [<%$, <%@, <%=, <%#...what's the deal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957284/whats-the-deal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Used for expressions, not code; often seen with DataSources

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx

Answer (score 7):

See this question:
[In ASP.Net, what is the difference between <%= and <%#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517721/in-asp-net-what-is-the-difference-between-and)

In summary ,there are a several different 'bee-stings':

- `<%@`  - Page/Control/Import/Register directive
- `<%$`  - Resource access and Expression building
- `<%=`  - Explicit output to page, equivalent to `<% Response.Write( ) %>`
- `<%#`  - [Data Binding.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)  It can only used where databinding is supported, or at the page level if you call `Page.DataBind()` in your code-behind.
- `<%`**--** - Server-side comment block
- `<%:`  - Equivalent to `<%=`, but it [also HTMLEncode()s the output](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It's markup used to evaluate expressions rather than code.

Comment: I would like to vote this up just because you took the effort and it's technically accurate.  However, it's not particularly helpful without further explanation.

Comment: Eh, I thought about deleting it. I ended my typing when the "1 new answer" popup came up. I hit the add button and it turns out the guy before me answered already so I didn't bother finishing.