# What is <%= ... %>

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

**For example:**

```
<input id="wineId" name="id" type="text" value="<%= id %>" />
```

I know it is printing the value of a JSON string id attribute ( i.e. {id:100} ).  But I am not finding any documentation on it, or even my Google-Fu can't find it.  [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201567/asp-net-what-is) assumes it is a Microsoft `Response.write()` method but I found it in a context having nothing to do with Microsoft code.

I was reading about [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) in general, this [four-part backbone tutorial by Christophe Coenraets](https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-cellar/tree/master/tutorial) specifically and [this particular page (line 4)](https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-cellar/blob/master/tutorial/final/tpl/wine-details.html)  particularly.

I've searched the "developer.mozilla.org" site under both html and javascript docs looking for it.  Am I blind?  Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: it looks like some ruby on rails to me

Comment: Looks like the Ruby on Rails syntax to run this code on the server and  print its result to the DOM. Is there another tool he's using that has similar syntax?

Comment: That can be pretty much any templating language.

Comment: Ruby, Java, and I think ASP also use the <% %> syntax. Either way it's almost definitely some back end code.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski read the tags

Comment: It's underscore, backbone.js uses that lib. Thanks @CrimsonChin  BTW, those tuts are the best I have found on backbone.js.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an underscore.js template.  It's used by backbone. See:  http://underscorejs.org/#template