# ASP.NET <%# versus <%

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm working on various asp.net pages .

For inline  functions I do see 2 different formats are used:

Example 1:

```
<p><%Response.Write(now())%></p>
```

I also see another one with #:

Example 2:

```
<Asp:TextBox id="Textbox5" width="40" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>' runat="server" />
```

I want to know what is the exact different , `<%# vs <%`

Comment: How did you guys found the duplicates???  I wonder when I was asking this question , those duplicates did Not show under "Questions that may already have your answer"  I also did a search but no similar results.

Comment: please comment on above...

Comment: Give it a try Search for <%# vs <% no related results. Search for <%# no results!!!

Comment: Anyway Thank for quick answers.

Comment: No big deal about not seeing existing answers to your question.  I had the post I linked bookmarked.  I think I stumbled onto it from google not that long ago.  It's good to see answers on stackoverflow show up at the top of your search results on google.

Comment: I found it by searching google for "ASP.net code blocks". searching for symbols is very difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good explanation here on stack -

[In ASP.Net, what is the difference between <%= and <%# [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517721/in-asp-net-what-is-the-difference-between-and)

Summary from those answers:

There are a several different 'bee-stings':

- `<%@` - Page/Control/Import/Register directive
- `<%$` - Resource access and Expression building
- `<%=` - Explicit output to page, equivalent to `<% Response.Write( ) %>`
- `<%#` - Data Binding. It can only used where databinding is supported,
  or at the page level if you call
- `Page.DataBind()` in your code-behind.
- `<%--` - Server-side comment block
- `<%:` - Equivalent to `<%=`, but it also html-encodes the output.

Comment: Very nice reference.  I wonder when I was asking this question , those duplicates did Not show under "Questions that may already have your answer"

Answer (score 3):

The former is simply denotes some .NET code in the markup that outputs to the page.

The later uses [Data Binding Expression Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to bind to a specific object.