# Using old school ASP.NET / C# backend with web.config - I need a dynamic connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string, code-behind

I have the following connection string in my `web.config`:

```
<add name="ConvMapping.Properties.Settings.ifl" 
     connectionString="Data Source=serverInfo;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`
```

The issue is now we have to use the database based on a selection.
So, example I want to do something like:

```
Data Source=serverInfo;Initial Catalog=Grant_database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password
```

or

```
Data Source=serverInfo;Initial Catalog=Wilson_database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password
```

where all databases will be named in the format `County_database`.

In the ASP.NET, in order to get this string now, I do the following:

```
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConvMapping.Properties.Settings.codes %>"
```

Another option is to add my connection strings in `web.config` for all possible instances, but then I'm not sure how to do the logic in the inline or code-behind areas to call the appropriate connection string, and initialize it as such.

One way I was thinking is to do a code behind switch-a-roo...

In the web config do:

```
Data Source=serverInfo;Initial Catalog={0}_database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password
```

Then in the `.aspx` do something like:

```
ConnectionString="<%# GetConnectionString() %>"
```

Then finally in the code behind do something like:

```
protected string GetConnectionString()
{
    var databaseName = string.Format(Properties.Settings.Default.codes, Request.QueryString["County"]);
    
    return databaseName ;
}
```

The issue is that I get the following error:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

I'm using the following technologies: C#, ASP.NET, SQL Server and the program is about 13 years old so a bit antiquated.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder) ? That would allow you to separate out the various parts of the connection string, have those that remain the same in your `web.config`, and add the dynamically generated name for the database at runtime, and get a ready-made connection string from code.

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm not sure how to call a method in the code-behind and then return that string back to the page...and then have it "initialize" the Connect String.

Comment: BTW there's something inherently dangerous about using `Request.QueryString["County"]` to build a connection string.

Comment: @Jamiec you mean _extremely_ dangerous. Using any raw values from a request is a bad idea, let alone for connecting to a database!

Answer (score 2):

The `string.Format()` plan is good, as long as you're not allowing users to type in arbitrary text for this. The problem is the so-called ["bee-sting"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/517742/3043):

```
<%#
```

That means to use Data-Binding, similar to an `Eval()` expression, and like the other bee stings happens far too late in the page life cycle.

Instead, you will want to omit the `ConnectionString` attribute from the `.aspx` file completely, and set the connection string for the data source as part of the code behind.

---

So if you currently have a datasource like this:

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1"
  SelectCommand="SELECT ... FROM ..."
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConvMapping.Properties.Settings.codes %>" 
  runat="server"/>
```

You would instead remove the ConnectionString attribute completely:

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1"
  SelectCommand="SELECT ... FROM ..."
  runat="server"/>
```

And then in the code-behind your page_load would include this:

```
SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString =  string.Format(Properties.Settings.Default.codes, Request.QueryString["County"]);
```

You *might* also be able to use an expression tag (`<%$`) to call the `GetConnectionString()` method, but it's been too long since I've used the old web forms for me to know for sure.

Comment: Ok I think that's what's happening here.  That's what is getting me now.  I moved the database setting to the page_load  like this:

`databaseName = string.Format(Properties.Settings.Default.codes, Request.QueryString["County"]);`

and tried to call it using it this way:

ConnectionString="<%=databaseName%>"

but then I get an invalid keyword error <%.

Comment: No, you can't call it using `<%=` either. That's still way too late in the life cyle (during the Rendering phase). You need to set the controls connection string property directly in the Page_Load.

Comment: I've been working on this for two days now to no avail. The issue is that the DropDownList I'm trying to populate doesn't seem to get created until the onrowupdating event is triggered.  That event isn't triggered until you hit the Update link, which is too late.  I need to be able to find the "DropDownList1" control when I hit the Edit link, then populate that control with the new SQL data. I'm guessing it has something to do with PostBack.  Just not sure how to capture it properly to only populate it when I hit the Edit link.

Answer (score 0):

if you have many connectionstrings I recommend you use this template in web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    ...
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
   ...
  </appSettings>
  
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn1" connectionString="Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;Uid=...;Pwd=...;..." />
    <add name="conn2" connectionString="Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;Uid=...;Pwd=...;..." />
  </connectionStrings>
...
</configuration>
```

And you can get them like this

```
using System.Configuration;
var conn1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn1"].ConnectionString;
var conn2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn2"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: That was the original setup.  The issue was that now, instead of loading the dropdownlist directly in the *.aspx page, I needed to load it in the code-behind since the connection to that DDL list varies based on what County was selected.  So I'm still using web.config to access the string, just getting the DDL to work was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up fixing the problem.

I put the DDL into the OnRowDataBound. From there I was able to load up the DropDownList.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
        {
            string query = "select a.code as NewActivityTypeID, a.name as NewActivityTypeDesc from code.activitytype a where deletedon is null";

            DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
            DropDownList1.DataSource = GetDropDownInfo(query);
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "NewActivityTypeID";
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "NewActivityTypeDesc";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(string.Empty, string.Empty));
}
```

My *.aspx page looks like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NewActivityTypeID" SortExpression="NewActivityTypeID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNewActivityTypeID" runat="server" SortExpression="Label1" Text='<%# Bind("NewActivityTypeID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```