# Output static property directly on .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, static-members

I want to output something like this on an aspx page (not codebehind):

```
<asp:text id="txt1" runat="server" value="<%# Fields.FirstName %>">
```

Where Fields.FirstName is a static class. How do I do this? I'm getting an error saying "The name 'Fields' does not exist in the current context". What am I missing? Do I have to include something on the .aspx page?

Comment: Have you called txt1.DataBind() in your PageLoad() code-behind (after qualifying Fields with the full name including the namespaces)?

Comment: I did not - should that matter? I'm just putting a value - if I put a string, it doesn't need that, right?

Comment: It matters because it is a server control. For non-server controls you can just populate it inline with the <%="value"%> notation.

Comment: What about if the control is in a repeater? How can I bind the controls?

Comment: Thanks! Please add as an answer, and I will mark it as such..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<input type="text" value="<%=Fields.FirstName %>" id="txt1" />
```

However, bear in mind that it is no longer a server control.

It is possible to use the <%# Fields.FirstName %> notation in server controls, however they will only be populated when you call DataBind from the code-behind. It is quite custom to use single quotes in the outer scope since double quotes are often needed in the inner scope, like here:

```
<input type="text" value='<%=Fields["FirstName"] %>' id="txt1" />
```

But if no quotes are needed it should also work as you described:

```
<asp:text id="txt1" runat="server" value="<%# Fields.FirstName %>">
```

As long as you call `txt1.DataBind()` somewhere in the code behind.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957284/whats-the-deal) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use the full class name (including all nested namespaces) and an = sign, you are not databinding (denoted by the # sign).  I commonly do this...

```
<%=Namespace.MyStrings.MyConstantString%>
```

Also, depending on how your page is setup, you might have to use single quotes areound the response write brackets....

```
<asp:TextBox ID="..." runat="server" Text='<%=Namespace.MyStrings.MyConstantString%>'></asp:TextBox>
```

**UPDATE:**

Super hacky, but I got it to work...

```
<supr:SuprTextBox ID="txt" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></supr:SuprTextBox>
<div id="preload" style="display:none;"><%=Supr.Strings.ASSET_CONTROL_LOCATION%></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#txt').val($('#preload').html());
    });
</script>
```

Had to redeem myself after the <%= syntax not working.

Comment: Where is the Fields class located?

Comment: its part of the same project.

Comment: My method call to a separate project (class library) in the same solution.  Does your project have a root namespace (is it a web application)?  Or is your class defined in the App_Code folder?

Comment: this class has a namespace - HS.CMS so I tried HS.CMS.Fields.FirstName, still no luck.

Comment: @TrueDevelopment you cannot use the <%="anything"%> notation in server controls.

Comment: My fault, just tested it and it appears to only be allowed with the databinding syntax.  You could use jquery - write into a span/div and copy over on doc ready.

Comment: It is possible to use the <%# "something" %> notation, but if I remember correctly you have to call Databind on the control from the code-behind for it to work. (if (!IsPostBack) { txt1.DataBind(); })

Comment: I think @LouisSomers just comment that above.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do this in the code behind or in a code snippet on the aspx page. You cannot nest asp tags (`<%# %>`) cannot be nested in the `asp:text` element.

Comment: maybe I am using the wrong tags - basically I want to be able to output that property... how do I do that?>