# How to write href1.rel=""; want to write on serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net

On html page i have

```
<a href="" id="href1" runat="server" rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: 'demos/imgProd/thumb-img2.jpg',largeimage: 'demos/imgProd/more-info-img1.jpg'}"></a>
```

I have to write **rel** content of **href** on server side(.cs)

like

```
href1.rel="";
```

But it is showing me an error how should i write??

Comment: @Downvoters: can we have reasons for down votes, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<%$, <%@, <%=, <%# ... what's the deal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957284/whats-the-deal)

Comment: Think so my question is poor so i am getting down votes

Comment: @Downvoters: If you are not understand the question then please again ask. don't voted down.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an attribute

```
href1.Attributes.Add("rel", "");
```