# Base tag is not working

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a path problem in my application. I'm trying to get the root url using right after `<title>` tage

```
<base href='<%# Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + '/'%>' />
```

But when I run the application and see through page source the the tag will be like

```
<base href= '' />
```

It is not getting the root url. I need suggestions on this please.

Regards,
Nuthan A R

Answer (score 1):

The `<%# %>` syntax is used for data binding. Those expressions are parsed when data binding occurs, so you need to invoke the `DataBind()` method in `Page_Load` method for example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

If you don't want to use data binding, you can simply change `<%# %>` to `<%= %>` and it will work properly:

```
<base href='<%= Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + '/'%>' />
```

Read more about it in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957321/1816426). A short quote:

> - `<%= %>` - is short-hand for `Response.Write` (discussed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx))
> - `<%# %>` - is used for [data binding expressions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860#1a).