# embedding Commerce Manager using an iframe element in MVC 4

Tags: iframe

I am working with a Commerce Manager and I need to be able to embed their payment system with my MVC 4 project.

Sample code below.

```
<iframe id="sFrame" width="200" height="300" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>https:/comManager.com/pay_school/rce_manager/payer.do?order=s_cart&contentEmbedded=true" frameborder="yes" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

I tried this but no luck. --- UPDATED CODE BELOW ----

```
<iframe id="sFrame" width="200" height="300" src="@System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath https:/comManager.com/pay_school/rce_manager/payer.do?order=s_cart&contentEmbedded=true" frameborder="yes" scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to java `getContextPath()` in .net is `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath`, not `UrlReferrer.Host`!

And according to [<%$, <%@, <%=, <%# ... what's the deal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957284) you should check your shorttag `@{}` or is this a MVC 4 specific thing I've never seen before?

Also I don't know where the sample code is from, but if the `comManager.com/pay_school` URL should be a (redirect)parameter, then you might URLencode it!

Comment: I updated the code above to reflex your suggestion. I now get this error **"A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)"** See screen shot [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qi1qj3zglfwlkd1/dangerouspath.png?dl=0) . BTW adding the @ sign at the begging its an MVC thing which is the same as <%= in APS.NET. Thanks.