# Eval does not work when using location.href property of Div tag

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am trying to make a `div` tag clickable . Following is the markup for it  :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 mb">
                            <div class="content-panel pn">
                                <div id="profile-01" style='<%# "background-image : url("+Eval("Photo").ToString()+") " %>'></div>
                                <div class="profile-01 centered" onclick="location.href='ProductDetails.aspx?ID=Eval("VendorItemID")' ">
                                    <p><%# Eval("Name") %></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="centered">
                                    <h5><i class="fa fa-gift"></i><br/><%# Eval("Description") %></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div><! --/content-panel -->
                        </div><! --/col-md-4 -->
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

My C# code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                VendorItemLogic vendorItem = new VendorItemLogic();
                DataTable dt = vendorItem.populateProducts(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]));

                rptr.DataSource = dt;
                rptr.DataBind();
            }
```

Now when I use `onClick` event of the `div` tag i get an error when i am using `Eval()` tag saying  : **The attribute name must be followed by an equal(=) sign and a value. If the value is in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match.**

And is it the best way to navigate to a different page using `location.href` property?

The purpose I want that ID in the Eval tag is because i want to access that ID on the other page and display that particular product's details .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the context switch to server-code in this attribute

```
onclick="location.href='ProductDetails.aspx?ID=Eval("VendorItemID")' "
```

it should be

```
onclick="location.href='ProductDetails.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("VendorItemID") %>' "
```

Comment: what is the difference between `<%# Eval() %>` and `<%: Eval() %>` ?? I guess it should be `<%# Eval() %>`... the latter gives error.

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957284/whats-the-deal (And you're right - ive updated the answer)

Comment: That was really helpful... In my case i did not want to use `Response.Write` hence `<%# %>` was useful to me .. Thanks anyways @Jamiec!