# #= operator in asp.net webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've looked at [<%$, <%@, <%=, <%# ... what's the deal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957284/whats-the-deal?lq=1)

but lately I've seen markup in webforms using the #= operator. Is this new? Or some client side framework being applied? Where can I get more information please and how does it compare with the other operators?:

```
<td><input type="text" name="ProductCountryProductName" value="#= (ProductName) ? ProductName : '' #" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="ProductCountryProductExpiryDate" value="#= formatDate(ProductExpiryDate) #" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ProductCountryIsAvailableEmployeeSite" #= IsAvailableEmployeeSite ? 'checked' : '' # /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ProductCountryIsAvailableCorporateSite" #= IsAvailableCorporateSite ? 'checked' : '' # /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ProductCountryIsAvailableBackOfficeSite" #= IsAvailableBackOfficeSite ? 'checked' : '' # /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ProductCountryIsAvailableSalesOrder" #= IsAvailableSalesOrder ? 'checked' : '' # /></td>
```

Comment: First: Does it work?

Comment: Where does this example come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a special binding for Telerik Controls.http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/listview/data-binding/client-side/overview#Section1_self