# Which data binding tags should be used in asp.net and javascript and jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, data-binding, javascript-databinding

1.<%: > `and`
2.<%= > `and`
3.<%# > `and`
4.<%$ > `and`
5.<%! > `.`

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957284/whats-the-deal)

Comment: Here is another reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976112.