# Nesting quotes in HTML > JavaScript > WebForms or how to call a .NET method in a JavaScript method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, double-quotes

Who would think so, but **I actually need 3 levels of nested quotes in an ASP.NET WebForms page.**

Here's what I have:

```
<img 
    src='<% ResolveClientUrl("~/SwissStyleguide/img/swiss.svg"); %>'
    onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='SwissStyleguide/img/swiss.png';" 
    alt="Confederatio Helvetica" 
/>
```

Now, the first part, assigning a dynamically created URL to the `src` attribute works fine. The server resolves the given special URL and creates an absolute link for the client to fetch.

But the `onerror` handler is more tricky: since the `src` URL to the png image is already in an expression with double quotes, I can not invoke the ASP.NET `ResolveClientUrl` method, which strictly requires double quotes for the string argument.

I tried to do it like this (does not work!)

```
<img 
    src='<% ResolveClientUrl("~/SwissStyleguide/img/swiss.svg"); %>'
    onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='<% ResolveClientUrl("~/SwissStyleguide/img/swiss.png"); %>';" 
    alt="Confederatio Helvetica" 
/>
```

But without much surprise, Visual Studio complains about this string. The only idea that comes to my mind is to use a string constant to avoid having the innermost quotes, but that seems very ugly.

**Is there a way to escape or otherwise specify some or all of the quotes to make that work?**

Note: I know about this question: [When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript) but changing the quotes does not help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,... this turned out as an instance of the **"<%$, <%@, <%=, <%# … what's the deal?"** WebForms problem, answered perfectly here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/957321/79485

The solution is to use the equal sign after the percent sign and omit the trailing semicolon. Like this:

```
onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/SwissStyleguide/img/swiss.png") %>';"
```

I'll leave the question and this answer here as a reminder of anyone tripping over this too.

Answer (score 1):

How about placing the attributes from the code-behind instead?

**.aspx**

```
<img id="image" runat="server" alt="Confederatio Helvetica" />
```

**.aspx.cs (Page_Load)**

```
image.Attributes.Add("src", Page.ResolveUrl("~/SwissStyleguide/img/swiss.svg"));
image.Attributes.Add("onerror", "this.onerror=null; this.src='" +
    Page.ResolveUrl("~/SwissStyleguide/img/swiss.png") + "';";
```

Comment: Yeah, this would work too. However, as I found out the quotes are not actually the problem.

Comment: Server.MapPath would give an absolute Path on the server system, not one that resolves from the client. You should change that in your answer.