# replace in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

is it possible to do globally string replacements on strings like  {myName1} in asp.net webforms?

I want to automatically replace given strings when the page loads. {myName1) can be found multiple in the text in default.aspx oder about-us.aspx etc.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Now if your next question is "how" then that's too broad of a question, but it should be pretty easy for you to come up with ideas on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an ASP.NET Webforms evaluate tag in your aspx page. See this page: [<%$, <%@, <%=, <%# ... what's the deal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957284/whats-the-deal)

For example, you could use

```
<%= MyName1 %>
```

and then define the value of myName1 as a string Property your codebehind class.

Comment: Thanks, like in old classic asp days: <%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("myName1") %>