# Can you tell the differences between <%= %>, <%# %> and <%$ %> ASP.NET expressions?

Tags: .net, asp.net, syntax

Can you briefly list the differences between `<%= %>`, `<%# %>` and `<%$ %>` by giving a simple example?

Maybe one that requires only one of those expressions to be used?

Comment: Did you read the documentation ? IIRC it's quite explicit on this subject

Comment: I wish VS gave a little more direction via intellisense or tooltips on what these mean.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [When should I use # and = in ASP.NET controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115159).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### <% %>

`<% this.CallMethod() %>` - [Basic code block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28vs.80%29.aspx) that executes the statements inside.

---

### <%= %>

`<%= "text" %>` - [Embedded code syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28VS.71%29.aspx). Same as writing `<% Response.Write("text") %>`.

---

### <%: %>

`<%: "text" %>` - Same as above except it's a shorthand for `<%= Server.HtmlEncode("text") %>`. This was [introduced in ASP.NET 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) and is the default syntax used.

---

### <%# %>

`<%# Eval("ColumnName") %>` - Used for [databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx).

---

### <%$ %>

`<%$ AppSettings: settingName %>` - The [expression syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx) has a prefix such as `AppSettings`, `ConnectionStrings`, or `Resources` and then a `:` followed by the actual expression. It can be used as a shorthand to access resources inline. You can even [create your own syntax](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304125044/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx) used here (Thanks @Thomas Levesque). Also [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder.aspx) for more info.

---

### <%@ %>

`<%@ Page language="C#" %>` - The [directive syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz702w3e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) useful for page/control settings.

---

### <%-- --%>

`<%-- This is a comment --%>` - [Server-side comment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/09/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Using-Server-Side-Comments-with-ASP.NET-2.0-.aspx) syntax. This differs from the HTML `<!-- a comment -->` syntax in that it *won't* be rendered in the output.

Comment: It's interesting to note that you can create your own expression syntax extensions for use with `<%$ %>`, although it isn't very well documented

Comment: @Thomas - I found a great article and MSDN info about the custom expressions (updated my post). You've opened a whole new world!

Comment: we have used this http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx expression builder for years, allows you to put any code you like in :)