# Differences between <%= and <%#?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have the following piece of code:

```
<div id='mymodal' class="modal hide fade <%# CssClass %>">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="closePopup" NavigateUrl='<%# CloseLink %>' CssClass="close" runat="server" >&times;</asp:HyperLink>
        <h3>
            <asp:Literal ID="header" Text='<%# Header %>' runat="server" />
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <asp:Literal ID="body" Text='<%# Body %>'  runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The first CssClass binding works either with <%# or <%=, while the other ones only work with <%# + codebehind DataBind() (if I use <%=, then the two Literals display literally the "<%= Body %>" text).

What is the use of both approaches? Why does it work this way? Which are the advantages of one over the other?

Comment: But why does it behave differently on an ASP.NET control and a html tag? They both should databind properties to public properties of code behind.

Comment: HTML tags can't databind.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115159/when-should-i-use-and-in-asp-net-controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Dan Crevier

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx

> The literal expression made it down to the browser and it's just
>   invalid HTML. What you can see as a result is:
>
> •The <%= expressions are evaluated at render time
>
> •The <%# expressions are evaluated at DataBind() time and are not
>   evaluated at all if DataBind() is not called.
>
> •<%# expressions can be used as properties in server-side controls.
>   <%= expressions cannot.

So in short `<%= %> is equivalent of Response.Write();` and

```
<%# %>  is used for data-binding expressions.
```

Answer (score 2):

> <%= is mean for Response.Write()
>
> <%# is used to data binding

referred From

[Can you tell the differences between <%= %>, <%# %> and <%$ %> ASP.NET expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565732/can-you-tell-the-differences-between-and-asp-net-expressio)

I hops this links helps to you lot...

Answer (score 0):

`<% %>` is for inclusion of server-side code to the Render() method

`<%# %>` is used for data-binding expressions

To know more delimiters:

[ASP.NET "special" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

Comment: Its between `<%= %>` and `<%# %>`, not `<%@ %>`

Comment: my apologies, it's my mistake, now corrected it