# ASP.net: What is the difference between <%, <%= and <%#?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use # and = in ASP.NET controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115159/when-should-i-use-and-in-asp-net-controls)

What is the difference, in ASP.net, between:

- `<% something %>`
- `<%= something %>`
- `<%# something %>`

Is any one a shortform of any other? Can any one be written as any other? When would i want to use any one over any other? In what situation should i use any one, rather than any other? What situation was any one designed for, rather than using any other? Is what situation should i *not* use any one over any other?

In other words:

> What's the difference between them?

**Note**: It's an impossible question to google for; given that the first answer is [What's the difference between a nerd, a geek, and a dork?](http://ask.yahoo.com/20060818.html)

---

Some examples of hypothetical syntax, that may or may not work, that may or may not demonstrate valid or invalid use of each syntax in hypothetical circumstances:

```
<% currentUser.Username %>
<%= currentUser.Username %>
<%# currentUser.Username %>

<% GetDisplayName() %>
<%= GetDisplayName() %>
<%# GetDisplayName() %>

<% GetColumnDayName(Container.DataItem) %>
<%= GetColumnDayName(Container.DataItem) %>
<%# GetColumnDayName(Container.DataItem) %>

<% Eval(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber")%>
<%= Eval(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber")%>
<%# Eval(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber")%>

<% Container.DataItem.Eval("PhoneNumber") %>
<%= Container.DataItem.Eval("PhoneNumber") %>
<%# Container.DataItem.Eval("PhoneNumber") %>

<% DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber")%>
<%= DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber")%>
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber")%>

<% Bind(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber") %>
<%= Bind(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber") %>
<%# Bind(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber") %>

<% DataBinder.Bind(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber") %>
<%= DataBinder.Bind(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber") %>
<%# DataBinder.Bind(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber") %>

<% Container.DataItem.Bind("PhoneNumber") %>
<%= Container.DataItem.Bind(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber") %>
<%# Container.DataItem.Bind(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber") %>
```

---

**Edit:** Are there any other *"escape characters"* besides `<%`, `<%=` and `<%#`? What is this called; escaping?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517721/in-asp-net-what-is-the-difference-between-and/517742#517742

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219/in-asp-net-what-are-the-different-ways-to-inline-code-in-the-aspx

Comment: reoepn the question because there are number thing...

Comment: @pranay - what "number thing"?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - here this are : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/384425/Server-side-Delimiters-in-ASP-NET

Comment: I wish I knew what these are called, the proper name for them?